# Errors processing query result set: Undefined variable and Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: mysql, joomla-3.6

I already have a database table called "form"; I added a new field in same table.

The problem is in the query `select * from "form"`. While the old fields display, the new field doesn't.

I have no idea why yet nothing displays; the query is correct. The error is:

> **Undefined variable: Num** in C:\xampp\htdocs\velocizzare\modules\mod_client\mod_client.php on line 96
>   **Trying to get property of non-object** in C:\xampp\htdocs\velocizzare\modules\mod_client\mod_client.php on line 96

My code is:

```
if(isset($_POST['BtnConsulter'])){
    $_SESSION["del"]=$_POST['BtnConsulter'];
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $db = JFactory::getDBO(); 
    $queri=$db->getQuery(true);
    $queri->select('*');
    $queri->from('ml0ak_chronoengine_chronoforms_datatable_formulaire');
    $queri->where('NuméroK10='.$_POST['BtnConsulter']);
    $db->setQuery ($queri); 
    $users = $db->loadObjectList();
    foreach ( $users as $us){
        $Cognome=$us->Cognome;
        $civilite=$us->civilite;
        $Email=$us->Email;
        $TelCellulaire=$us->TelCellulaire;
        $AutreTel=$us->AutreTel;
        $DataDiNascita=$us->DataDiNascita;
        $Ville=$us->Ville;
        $PaysNaissance=$us->PaysNaissance;
        $ResidenteInCitta=$us->ResidenteInCitta;
        $Provincia=$us->Provincia;
        $Num->$us->Num;                                      // <-- Line 96

        );

        echo"<br />Nome: $Nome";
        echo"<br />Cognome: $Cognome";
        echo"<br />E-mail: $Email";
        echo"<br />Tel/Cellulare: $TelCellulaire";
        echo"<br />Autre Tel: $AutreTel";
        echo"<br />Data di nascita: $DataDiNascita";
        echo"<br />Ville: $Ville";
        echo"<br />Pays de Naissance: $PaysNaissance";
        echo"<br />Residente in (Citta): $ResidenteInCitta";
        echo"<br />Provincia: $Provincia";
        echo"<br /> Num: $Num";
```

**I cleared the cache, it does not work**
[image]
Please what's the solution?

The result: [image]

Answer (score 2):

Problem is this `$Num->$us->Num;`. You're not defining it correctly.

So replace it with this:

```
$Num = $us->Num;
```

---

You may also want to improve your code a little. Try the following:

```
$jinput       = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$BtnConsulter = $jinput->get('BtnConsulter', '');

if ($BtnConsulter)
{
    $user    = JFactory::getUser();
    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    $db      = JFactory::getDbo(); 

    $session->set('del', $BtnConsulter);

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('*')
          ->from($db->qn('#__chronoengine_chronoforms_datatable_formulaire'))
          ->where($db->qn('NuméroK10') . ' = ' . $db->q($BtnConsulter));
    $db->setQuery ($query); 

    $users = $db->loadObjectList();

    foreach ($users as $us)
    {
        $Cognome          = $us->Cognome;
        $civilite         = $us->civilite;
        $Email            = $us->Email;
        $TelCellulaire    = $us->TelCellulaire;
        $AutreTel         = $us->AutreTel;
        $DataDiNascita    = $us->DataDiNascita;
        $Ville            = $us->Ville;
        $PaysNaissance    = $us->PaysNaissance;
        $ResidenteInCitta = $us->ResidenteInCitta;
        $Provincia        = $us->Provincia;
        $Num              = $us->Num;

        echo "<br>Nome: $Nome";
        echo "<br>Cognome: $Cognome";
        echo "<br>E-mail: $Email";
        echo "<br>Tel/Cellulare: $TelCellulaire";
        echo "<br>Autre Tel: $AutreTel";
        echo "<br>Data di nascita: $DataDiNascita";
        echo "<br>Ville: $Ville";
        echo "<br>Pays de Naissance: $PaysNaissance";
        echo "<br>Residente in (Citta): $ResidenteInCitta";
        echo "<br>Provincia: $Provincia";
        echo "<br>Num: $Num";
    }
}
```

When declaring the result set variables inside of the `foreach()` loop, use spacing/tabs to align the `=` assignment operator.  This will help you to see any inconsistencies in your code.  This technique is employed in a few places in the [Joomla's php coding standards document](https://developer.joomla.org/coding-standards/php-code.html):

Comment: @helabriki please take the time to award Lodder's answer with the green tick so that this page is deemed resolved.  He has taken the time to not only correct your typo but offer additional advice.  "Accepting" an answer also rewards volunteers who take the time to craft correct and helpful answers.

Comment: The `isset($BtnConsulter)` check is useless, right? Isn't the empty string 2nd param on `get()` ensuring that the variable will contain something and be set? I don't see `NuméroK10` in the screenshot so I don't know what an appropriate default value should be.  Maybe `empty()` or `==''` might be better a check.

Comment: @mickmackusa - yes, `isset` probably isn't the best check to perform